# The same functionality in DevExpress GridView and BandedGridView descendants

Tags: gridview, devexpress

I've extended DevExpress GridView and GridControl controls with custom functionality guided by this topic - http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/A859 and it works as I expected (I've created own descendants for GridControl, GridView, GridHandler and GridInfoRegistrator). But now I need to extend BandedGridView with the same functionality.
I keep the main logic in CustomGridView (delegates, events, public methods) and I don't want to create CustomBandedGridView with duplicated code.

Where I should put my logic which would be accessible both for CustomGridView and CustomBandedGridView and still have access to base methods for GridView.

What would be the best approach to avoid code duplication?

Comment: I use Delphi version of DevEx, so at the risk of being wrong, I assume the internal architecture is similar.
In addition to (or instead of) customizing views directly you want to write a DataController descendant, it should be used by all views.